# Best way to simulate 'wrap' in python

Tags: python

I'm looking for the best way, how to write wrap function in python (2.6). This function takes a command (function call) as parameter and terminates the script when that call didn't go well (returned error value). The main problem I see is that when there is nested call which fails, wrap must detect this event and terminate script as well. 
For instance

```
def foo1(x):
    y = foo2(x)
    return y

def foo2(y):
    y = 2**y
    return y
```

Then I use wrap like this:

```
wrap(foo1(2))
```

Please consider this example as extremely simplified.

The thing is that wrap must detect when error occurs even in foo2.

Comment: Can't you simply use `try...except` to trap the errors in `wrap` function?

Comment: The question is not that clear for me. Exceptions will propagate and you can catch them at any level.

Comment: I think that I will have to use try, but I might want to wrap executable application (as  subprocess). Will try itself handle this error as well?

Comment: show code that you have problem with. in fact, do you have a problem at all?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you start poking around with Python's bytecode there is no clear way to do what you ask. And even then, it is not clear either what does error detection mean, because you may want to call other functions from your code, like to calculate the `sqrt` of a number:

```
>>> def foo3(y):
...   y = sqrt(5)
...   return y
...
```

What does an error on `sqrt` mean?

The two most common ways to test code are:

(1) Just care about one single value. If you want to test more than one function, test each one individually:

```
wrap(foo1(2))
wrap(foo2(2))
wrap(foo3(2))
```

(2) Use exceptions. Each function is responsible of signaling an error, and from wrap you detect that error:

```
def wrap(f, args, kwargs={}):
  try:
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  except:
    print("Error on f")

def main():
  wrap(foo1, (2, ))
  wrap(foo2, (2, ))
  wrap(foo3, (2, ))
```